# This is a AT-ST but I cannot identify what set it goes to

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

This is a AT-ST but I cannot identify what set it goes to.
Can you help me?

[image: Star Wars AT-ST]

Answer (score 6):

This is from

[8038: The Battle of Endor](https://brickset.com/sets/8038-1/The-Battle-of-Endor)

[image]

Keypart :
[Dark Bluish Gray Plate, Modified 6 x 8 Trap Door Frame Horizontal](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30041&colorID=85&in=A)